# Нужно ли выделять запятыми подчинённую часть "где находишься" с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

— Должно быть, не терпится узнать, где находишься и кто я такая? — поигрывая кинжалом, усмехнулась незнакомка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, с двух сторон выделять не нужно, так как прямая речь в Вашем примере — это СПП с двумя придаточными, относящимися к одному главному.

[Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139)

> Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится: *Отец мой говорил, что он не видывал таких хлебов **и** что нынешний год урожай отличный.*